# Maximo classification summary query

Tags: maximo

*Maximo Asset Management 7.6.1.2; Oracle 19c:*

I want to summarize the CLASSSTRUCTURE and CLASSUSEWTIH tables as follows in a db view:

- CLASSSTRUCTUREID
- LEVEL number
- LEVEL_COUNT
- CLASSIFICATIONID
- HIERARCHYPATH (existing custom persistent field in CLASSSTRUCTURE)
- PARENT
- TOP_CLASSSTRUCTUREID
- TOP_CLASSIFICATIONID
- USEWTIH

[image]

How can I do that with Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 1):

I can use Oracle hierarchical querying (CONNECT BY):

```
--create or replace view cgclassstructure_vw as (
select
    cl.classstructureid,
    level as pseudo_level, --the CLASSANCESTOR table already has an OOB HIERARCHYLEVEL column. But the level numbers in that column are in reverse-order (sorted descending) and the level numbers start at 0 instead of 1 -- which isn't what we want.
    count(level) over (partition by connect_by_root(cl.classificationid)) as level_count,
    cl.classificationid,
    cl.description,
    cl.cghierarchypath,
    --ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(cl.classificationid, ' \ '),' \ ') as hierarchypath,
    cl.parent,
    cl.haschildren,
    connect_by_root(cl.classstructureid) as top_classstructureid,
    connect_by_root(cl.classificationid) as top_classificationid,
    uw.usewith,
    cl.cgactive
from 
    maximo.classstructure cl
left join
    (
    select 
        classstructureid,
        listagg(objectname,', ') within group(order by objectname) as usewith
    from 
        maximo.classusewith
    group by 
        classstructureid
    ) uw
    on cl.classstructureid = uw.classstructureid
start with cl.parent is null
connect by prior cl.classstructureid = parent
order by
    top_classstructureid,  --handles scenarios like the FACILITIES classifications -- we have top-level FACILITIES classifications for both ASSET and WO (different sets of classifications)
    cghierarchypath
--)
```

[image]